# Dispatch.yaml routing to a specific module version?

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

If there a way to route a custom subdomain (something.mydomain.com) to a specific version of a module?

This would mean I can use the following:

www.mydomain.com - production site
dev.mydomain.com - testing site

I tried using the following in dispatch.yaml, but I got an error when trying to update it

```
- url: "dev.mydomain.com/*"
  module: dev.app
```

The error was:

> Error parsing yaml file:
>   Unable to assign value 'dev.app' to attribute 'module':
>   Value 'dev.app' for module does not match expression '^(?:^(?!-)[a-z\d-]{0,62}[a-z\d]$)$'
>     in ".\dispatch.yaml", line 15, column 13

I know you can target versions in the queue.yaml, and CRON (i think) so why not dispatch?

Answer (score -2):

If you read the error closely, you will notice it is complaining about the module name dev.app...

Rename your module to dev-app and try again.

Comment: If I renamed the module, it will no longer be a version of my main module. E.g "app" is the module name, with a version name of "1" (for example. "dev" is a version name, for a sub version of the "app" module. I can use dev.app.<projectname>.appspot.com to access the "dev" version of "app". If I rename the dev version to a new module name, its now a new module. In queue.yaml I can target a version of my "app" using "dev.app" (note the period)